# Using python files with libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, python, wpf, ironpython, python.net

I want to use some python files in a Visual Studio WPF application, using this code.

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("Test.py");
string whatever = test.pythonString()
MessageBox.Show(whatever);
```

where Test.py looks like this:

```
def pythonString:
   return "Whatever"
```

everything works as expected but if I add any import like

```
from moviepy.editor import *
```

to the python code the messagebox doesn't appear. Why does this happen and what do I have to change in order to make python work in Visual studio with libraries?

EXTRA INFO:
I use Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7.

I set up IronPython like this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2009/10/25/running-ironpython-scripts-from-a-c-4-0-program/

Comment: you need to install `pip install moviepy`, but it does not work on IronPython! So try pythonnet (Python for .NET) from CPython.